# Application error, undefined symbol: rb_thread_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, pg, heroku-postgres

I have an RoR application everything was working fine until I deployed to heroku where I get the "Application Error" and on the logs "undefined symbol: rb_thread_select", I'm using "ruby 2.3.0p0", "Rails 4.2.5" gem 'pg', '0.18.4', any ideas how to fix it?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'foundation-rails'

gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"

gem 'devise'

gem 'redis', '~> 3.0.1'
gem 'hiredis', '~> 0.4.5'

# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# gem 'unicorn'

# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: Can you add your gemfile

Comment: luissimo, just added the gem file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.3.0'


gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'foundation-rails'

gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"

gem 'devise'

gem 'redis', '~> 3.0.1'
gem 'hiredis', '~> 0.4.5'

# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# gem 'unicorn'

# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
 gem 'pg'
 gem 'rails_12factor'
 gem 'puma'
end
```

Copy and paste this gemfile and run **bundle install** in your terminal.

Comment: thanks! that wasn't exactly the problem but it help me understand the problem !

Comment: Glad you fixed it, please accept the answer if it helped you out :)

Comment: Really, `background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring` is a valid ruby line?